# Doctrine fromArray bug?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I have a problem with doctrine with this code I can't explain.

```
public function fromArray(array $array, $deep = true) {
    $refresh = false;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if ($key == '_identifier') {
            $refresh = true;
            $this->assignIdentifier($value);
            continue;
        }
```

My key (integer) 0 will equal (string) '_identifier'. Is this a bug in PHP or is this normal? or am I doing something wrong?

When I change the code to `$key === '_identifier'` it works. I have PHP version 5.3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's PHP:

```
echo (int) '_identifier'; // 0
```

And 0 equals 0. In the comparison operation the string is changed into integer to compare it.

Use [`===`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to do a comparison of the same type as well. Called identical, not equal:

```
public function fromArray(array $array, $deep = true) {
    $refresh = false;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if ($key === '_identifier') {
        $refresh = true;
        $this->assignIdentifier($value);
        continue;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand:

`==` is just generic comparing, so if your key is an integer it will convert the string to an integer to compare it and [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> The value is given by the initial
>   portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this
>   will be the value used. Otherwise, the
>   value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric
>   data is an optional sign, followed by
>   one or more digits (optionally
>   containing a decimal point), followed
>   by an optional exponent. The exponent
>   is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or
>   more digits.

`===` is strict evaluation so it compares types too.

So when you do "`0 == '_identifier'`" it passes as it evaluated `'_identifier'` as 0.
When you do "`0 === '_identifier'`" it does not pass as they are different types.